# Menu is not appearing in the main activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm studying Android now and I got stuck with one issue which I could solve.
The menu is not appearing in the top of my simple application:

```
<menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item android:id="@+id/red_button"
        android:title="@string/red"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/green_button"
        android:title="@string/green"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
        android:title="@string/yellow"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</group>

</menu>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.emad.menuapp.MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        RelativeLayout lay=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);


        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case(R.id.red_button):
                if (item.isChecked())
                    item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);

                lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                return true;

            case(R.id.green_button):
                if (item.isChecked())
                    item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                return true;

            case(R.id.yellow_button):
                if (item.isChecked())
                    item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                lay.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                return true;

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden because you set `app:showAsAction="never"` in the menu XML file.
Update the value with `always` instead of `never`

Comment: thanks now i'm testing the Application on Jelly Bean 4.3 still it is not showing as drop down list it showing the items on one row in the menu any idea why it is showing like this

Comment: If you want to have one icon in the action bar and a dropdown for it with the rest of the items you will need to have a structure like this: `<item><menu>....</menu></item>` and inside the menu have the 3 items that you are using now. Have a look at this example that i've made: http://pastebin.com/KtdsPxB2